# Повторное открытие файл для записи

Tags: java, filewriter

Здравствуйте! Вот такой вопрос, у меня есть 2 функцию одна вызывает другую N раз, та функция, которую вызывают, открывает файл и делает записи, но у меня не получается сделать так, чтобы старые записи оставались. Не подскажите как это сделать можно?

Comment: Приведите ваш код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял Ваш вопрос...

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Создание тестового файла
        File file = new File("Test.txt");

      if(!file.exists()){              //если файл не существует то будет создан
          PrintWriter out = null;

          try {
              out = new PrintWriter(file);                    
          } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
              out.println("21.5,-51.7,1.0");//Double
              out.close();
      }
      for (int i = 0; i <3 ; i++) {
        writeToLog(file.getAbsolutePath(), "some test data", true);
        //путь,данные, если true - дописывать в файл(false - обнулять предыдущие записи)
    }

    }


    private static void writeToLog(String outPath2, String newData, boolean appendData) {
        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(outPath2, appendData);
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(newData + System.getProperty("line.separator")); //занесение данных в файл + перенос строки
        } catch (IOException e) {
        } finally {
            if (bw != null) {
                try {
                    bw.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

При открытии файла стандартными средствами Java SE есть возможность указать атрибуты с помощью класса перечисления [StandardOpenOption](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html)
В Вашем случае, необходимо указать WRITE (открытие на запись), CREATE (создать файл если его не существует), APPEND (производить запись начиная с позиции конца файла)